# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried hard to find this error, deleted all unnecessary nodes. but still,

I can't find it.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input         test.html:28

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>파일 다운로드</title>
</head>


<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <table width="500" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="blueone">

      <tr>
        <th>파일명</th>
        <th>진행상황</th>
        <th>다운로드</th>
        <th>시정지</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="100Mb.dat">File10MB</td>
        <td><progress id="progress" value="0"></progress><span id="display"></span>       </td>
        <td class="test"><a class="checkBtn checkBtn1" onclick="downloadFile(event, "100Mb.dat")">다운로드</a></td> //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
        <td><a class="pauseBtn pauseBtn1" onclick="stop(1);" value="ACTION">일시정지</a><a class="resumeBtn resumeBtn1" onclick="resume(1);" value="ACTION">다시시작</a></td>
      </tr>

    </table>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `onclick="downloadFile(event, "100Mb.dat"` You forgot to escape. Better to attach handler properly using Javascript instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside double-quote use semi-quote mark like this:

```
onclick="downloadFile(event, '100Mb.dat')"
```

All code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>파일 다운로드</title>
</head>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/myscript.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="js/downloadJs.js"></script> -->
    <script src="js/distribute.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <table width="500" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="blueone">
      <tr>
        <th>파일명</th>
        <th>진행상황</th>
        <th>다운로드</th>
        <th>시정지</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="100Mb.dat">File10MB</td>
        <td><progress id="progress" value="0"></progress><span id="display"></span></td>
        <td class="test"><a class="checkBtn checkBtn1" onclick="downloadFile(event, '100Mb.dat')">다운로드</a></td>
        <td><a class="pauseBtn pauseBtn1" onclick="stop(1);" value="ACTION">일시정지</a><a class="resumeBtn resumeBtn1" onclick="resume(1);" value="ACTION">다시시작</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

As said in the error, line 28:

```
onclick="downloadFile(event, "100Mb.dat")"
```

You are using double quotes for `"100Mb.dat"`, which is breaking the `onclick` ones. And browser parses (understands) it this way..

```
onclick="downloadFile(event, "         100Mb.dat          ")"
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with

```
onclick="downloadFile(event, "100Mb.dat")"
```

You can't have double quotes within double quotes here.

Either escape the inner quotes or use single quotes for one pair.